# authentication token manipulation error,password unchanged

Tags: linux, bash, grub, authentication, passwd

I've been battling my Toshiba satellite with Kali Linux and the 2017 ISO file installed. After trying to update and upgrade the system, it crashed, and I tried rebooting it; then, it kept changing from the grub boot mood till eternity until I started testing the tty1,2,3 console, but I kept getting incorrect password despite inputting the original and known password I created the box with. So I started editing the grub booting with the "rw init=/bin/bash code, and then I learned I can't even change my password even after mounting the drive and changing permissions. The sudo command doesn't work, and I get this libcrypt.so.1.1 error.

The images contain a few of the commands I've tried. Also, when I do pam-auth-update, it says unable to access the libcrypt file. And I can't view the whole files listed to sport the exact lib script because I can't scroll up from the boot console to check the entire files listed.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmmwc.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvqDE.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b8ks.jpg]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvqDE.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM3SN.jpg]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVRPL.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Your system is definitely broken, most likely beyond repair.

It would be best to backup all data and reinstall it.

Note that Kali Linux is not meant to be installed in most cases.

Also you are using a 5 years old (!) release of the OS, it is very unlikely that you will have a stable experience with it.

Comment: I’m really sad and broken via what you said. Did you view the images attached?. I asked because i felt there’s a way to revive the system back. I tried almost anything i did find online to make it work but nothing worked And the worst part is i don’t know which is the exact fault via the password criteria.

Comment: Also there’s no way to login and backup my files since i’m locked out.